# Unity projects and building

Tags: unity, build-process

I've made my first game, in Unity, and I want to upload it to MediaFire.

I'm not sure what to upload. Should I upload the whole project, or is a certain part enough for someone to play it?

Comment: I want to uplo only the game so someone can poax it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to upload your game for others to play, you should only have to upload the *build*. This is the executable that is created when you build your project.

In contrast, you should only upload your *entire project* if you intend for users to have access to your Unity project.

---

For further direction, [follow this YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xDTWQOkUlx0).

Comment: do you mean exe file?

Comment: this video covers building a project: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xDTWQOkUlx0